# Laravel session configuration with database type SESSION_DRIVER

Tags: php, mysql, session, laravel-8

I have installed `auth` in a `Laravel 8` project. Now I need to configure the `session.php` for `database` type `SESSION_DRIVER`, for which I have created and run the following commands:

```
php artisan session:table
composer dump-autoload
```

and then run `php artisan migrate` for following migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSessionTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
            $table->string('id')->primary();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->index();
            $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
            $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
            $table->text('payload');
            $table->integer('last_activity')->index();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('session');
    }
}
```

after doing the following changes in `config\session.php` file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

'expire_on_close' => true,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

// 'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
| list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
| must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
|
| Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
|
*/

'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', config('app.name')), '_').'_session'
),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Same-Site Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
| take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
| will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
|
| Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
|
*/

'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

Now, `session` is still trying to save the session in file in `projectroot\storage\framework\sessions\` directory from where the session file have got deleted so it gives the following error:

```
file_put_contents(/Yijc8g3gyiTvmTftMX7FyUOTI7OyPGH3N0Weve7g): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

but this error is not needed to be resolved, the issue is that why the application is using `file` type `SESSION_DRIVER` and not `database` type driver which I need. Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: have you tried after clearing cache

Comment: Yes @Shibon it was not the cause, resolved using ```.env``` settings.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it, in the `.env` file, the default `SESSION_DRIVER=file` was set which also needed to be changed to `SESSION_DRIVER=database` type. While `debugging` the `SessionServiceProvider` inside function `registerSessionManager()`, dumping the configs `new SessionManager($app)` gave me session configuration with `SESSION_DRIVER=file`.